# How does Mutual Information handle background overlap

Tags: mutual-information

I have been reading about mutual information in Image Registration. It's in the literature that MI is better able to handle the cases with the large background where anatomical structures are not aligned than entropy. Can someone provide intuitive information regarding how can MI handle such cases? Thanks in advance